# Changing an element on checked where parent is not shared

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to make some text in a `h1` move down the screen by 20 pixels when an `input` checkbox is checked. I'm aware of the `+` and `~` operators, but these both need the `input` and the `h1` to share a parent, which is not the case with my DOM:

```css
.title {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.box:checked ~ .title {
  transform: translateY(20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="some-element">
  <input type="checkbox" class="box"/>
</div>

<div class="some-other-element">
  <h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

If I move the `input` inside the `div.some-other-element`, the transition works fine, but since I need the `input` to be inside `div.some-element` I can't do that.

Can I trigger the transition on `div.some-other-element` when `input` is checked using pure CSS? If not, is there a way I can easily do it with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't pure `css` solution, as there is no `parent css` selector. You can accomplish it with jQuery, and simply `toggling` the transition class:
**jQuery**

```
$('.box').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('.some-element').next('.some-other-element').find('.title').toggleClass('someclass');

});
```

**CSS**

```
.someclass{
  transform: translateY(20px);
}
.title {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Check the **below snippet**

```js
$('.box').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('.some-element').next('.some-other-element').find('.title').toggleClass('someclass');

});
```

```css
.someclass {
  transform: translateY(20px);
}
.title {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-element">
  <input type="checkbox" class="box" />
</div>

<div class="some-other-element">
  <h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum</h1>
</div>

<div class="some-element">
  <input type="checkbox" class="box" />
</div>

<div class="some-other-element">
  <h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution, but it doesn't animate like I want it to.

Comment: Isn't `position:relative;` better as it has better support than [transform](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)? Or even `margin-top` because it would push the surrounding elements?

Comment: @LarsW I guess this is simplified problem by OP to solve the problem of selecting the next `.title` element and animating it.

Comment: @itsgoingdown That's true. It's not clear what method OP would prefer, and this is a good solution.

Comment: nvm, didn't even see that the OP uses `transform`. Sorry.

Comment: This is just what I was after. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is` to see if `input` is `:checked` and then animate `margin-top`

```js
$('input.box').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.title').animate({
      'margin-top': '100px'
    });
  } else {
    $('.title').animate({
      'margin-top': '20px'
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-element">
  <input type="checkbox" class="box" />
</div>

<div class="some-other-element">
  <h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I've accepted itsgoingdown's answer because the animation can be reversed before it's completed, making it look better for a sliding menu.

Answer (score 1):

**This solution is not actually functioning right now, but it might be very interesting in the future, because it is a CSS-only solution. It might become impossible anyway, if they change the specs.**

The [CSS Level 4 selectors](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/) specifies the relational [`:has()` selector](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational), which effectively is the replacement of the parent selector, as you can select children without descending in the DOM. With the current rules, this would probably be the solution:

```css
.title {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.some-element:has(.box:checked) ~ .some-other-element .title {
  transform: translateY(20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="some-element">
  <input type="checkbox" class="box"/>
</div>

<div class="some-other-element">
  <h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for posting this.